# How to autocomplete an input from and API url on wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, autocomplete, request

I am trying to make a request on an API, from an input. I want to autocomplete airport,cities suggestions etc.

I need to do this on Wordpress and i keep getting an error. This is what i did:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#autocompletedep").autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "https://www.fly-go.ro/ajax_autocomplete_flight?temp=",
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    q: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    var user = new String()
                    user = data.Title;
                    for (i = 0; i < user.length; i++) {
                        $('#autocompletedep')
                            .append($('<option>', { value: user[i] })
                                .text(user[i]));
                    }
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

I am not sure if i am doing the right way.
The error is:

flight-search.js?ver=5.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at flight-search.js?ver=5.3:1

Any help would be very appreciated, thank you!

Comment: is the jQuery is loaded?

Comment: No, everything stucks at that error..

Comment: What I meant was have added the jQuery script on the code?

Comment: yes, it is added

Comment: Can you add your HTML in the code?